# How to parse iterate-name json with retrofit?

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I am working with Retrofit and `GSON`. I have a `JSON` response as a `JSONArray` but I don't know how to parse it by using a model class. My response is as follows:

```
{  
   "1":{  
      "id":"1",
      "parentid":"0",
      "posi":"1",
      "name":"\u0418\u043d\u0444\u043e\u0440\u043c\u0430\u0446\u0438\u044f",
      "alt_name":"main",
      "icon":"",
      "skin":"",
      "descr":"",
      "keywords":"",
      "news_sort":"",
      "news_msort":"",
      "news_number":"0",
      "short_tpl":"",
      "full_tpl":"",
      "metatitle":"",
      "show_sub":"0",
      "allow_rss":"1"
   },
   "5":{  
      "id":"5",
      "parentid":"1",
      "posi":"1",
      "name":"Edited cat name",
      "alt_name":"newcater2",
      "icon":"",
      "skin":"",
      "descr":"",
      "keywords":"",
      "news_sort":"",
      "news_msort":"",
      "news_number":"0",
      "short_tpl":"",
      "full_tpl":"",
      "metatitle":"",
      "show_sub":"1",
      "allow_rss":"1"
   }
}
```

Comment: Show us your code that you have tried, about how did you get that json response using retrofit

Comment: Did you manage to solve this, because i have a similar issue?